# Is there anyway to use comma in search bar for displaying multiple row in SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

So, I have created a search bar and connected to the database. Everything is fine and now I wanted to try to create a search bar that can detect multiple keywords in the search bar. Below is the example of my database:

```
+------+--------------+
| Bil. | ID | Product |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | G1 | M1 Plus |
| 2    | G2 | M1 Plus |
| 3    | G3 | Omega 3 |
+------+--------------+
```

I wanted to use comma as a separator for detecting the keyword in the search bar for ID example when I search "G1, G2", it will display the both of the row.

I tried to use this code

```
SELECT ID FROM Egg WHERE (',' + ID + ',') OR (ID + ',') OR (',' + ID) OR (ID) LIKE '" & @ID_search & "';"
```

Is there anything I had to improve to even better one?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input on the commas and then construct your SQL based on the parts, e.g.

```vb
Dim keywords = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
Dim criteria As New List(Of String)
Dim command As New SqlCommand

For i = 0 To keywords.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim keyword = keywords(i)
    Dim parameterName = $"@SomeColumn{i}"

    criteria.Add($"SomeColumn LIKE {parameterName}")
    command.Parameters.Add(parameterName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = $"%{keyword}%"
Next

Dim sql = $"SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE {String.Join(" OR ", criteria)}"

command.CommandText = sql
```

If you enter *G1* then that will yield:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn LIKE @SomeColumn0
```

If you enter *G1,G2,G3* then that will yield:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn LIKE @SomeColumn0 OR SomeColumn LIKE @SomeColumn1 OR SomeColumn LIKE @SomeColumn2
```

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney! Just curious, is there possible that SQL can do similar function like detect?

Comment: @Stevie99, you could split the input in the SQL code but that sort of stuff is much more laborious in SQL that it is in a language designed for stuff like that.

Comment: Ok, but what if u decide to use SQL for such function. Is there any tips for that?